# Share and update the static collection across the web api requests (user sessions)

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-web-api, static, asp.net-web-api2

I need each user requestid to store in static collection object. on each next request need to check if same user request exist then process some specific task using it.

So, to achieve this, I am thinking to preserve `static list` object. but as in web requests it will not give me correct value or update collection correctly because of static object in web.

can you please share me what is the ideal approach here, I should use or way to handle static collection object in web (while updating collection or retrieving collection).

Comment: Ideal approach would be to use database. In case your API goes down, data would still be preserved in the DB.

Comment: In case need to keep in memory then, how to handle the static collection for add/update across the web api requests sessions.

Comment: At least use a concurrent collection: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373(v=vs.110).aspx. Maybe use `MemoryCache` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477235.aspx

Comment: Ok, I'll check by implementing concurrent dictionary. do you think, Redis is good option ? basically , need to store in server side memory ony.

Comment: @Peter Bons it works for me, you can add as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to build it yourself then at least use a concurrent collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997373(v=vs.110).aspx since you will be accessing the collection from multiple threads.

Otherwise I suggest using MemoryCache, a thread-safe built-in mechanism. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff477235.aspx

Comment: concurrent collection is works for me. quick way to achieve threadsafe operations.